# Vectorizing a for loop of a logical comparison of vectors of different length in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vector, comparison

In `R` vectors of different lengths cannot be meaningfully compared, i.e.

```
x = 1:10
y = 7:12
x >= y
```

gives a warning that `y` is shorter than `x`. I would like to cary out a comparison of each element of `x` to `y` and save or transform the resulting vector as in

```
v = numeric()
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  v[i] = sum( x[i] >= y )
}
```

This operation is slow - is there a direct way to get here? Alternatiely to `sum` consider saving `i` in rows of  a matrix `v[i,]`.

Comment: Try `colSums(sapply(x, '>=', y))`  or `rowSums(outer(x, y, FUN= '>='))`

Comment: @akrun thanks that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `outer` and `rowSums`

```
rowSums(outer(x, y, FUN= '>='))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4
```

---

Or another option is looping with `sapply` and then get the `colSums` of the logical matrix

```
colSums(sapply(x, '>=', y))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4
```

---

We can also translate the `for` loop in `Rcpp`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

//[[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector getSum(NumericVector v1, NumericVector v2) {
    NumericVector v(v1.size());

    for(int i = 0; i <= v1.size(); i++) {
        v[i] = sum(v1[i] >= v2 );


    }
    return(v);



}
```

-from R console

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("rcppTrial.cpp")
getSum(x, y)
 #[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4
```